# How to securely keep track of membership status in a web app

Tags: node.js, database, stripe-payments

I'm building a web app for a client and I've never worked on a membership feature before.

I am using Node for the backend, Stripe for monthly payments, and mongo as a database.

I am planning to have a regular and a premium membership option. The regular membership is free(can still make an account) but won't have access to some features and the premium membership will have all the features. How would I securely keep a record of who has a regular account and who has a premium account?

I feel like it wouldn't be secure to keep a list of user id in some sort of database like mongo and check upon login whether they are premium. Or would it?

Comment: why wouldn't it be secure?
the question is very broad, are you asking about security concerns/approches? design of a solution like this? libraries?
also, what are the use cases/user stories? what does the client want?

Comment: Im asking about security concerns.  I thought that storing in a db would cause it to be vulnerable to hackers because they can easily just change their membership status.

Comment: I'm not a security expert but, I would think about avoiding OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities instead.
Regarding the design, first of all, make sure that what the client wants is feasible with whatever design you decide. Perhaps a Role Based Access Control is a good enough approach for this.